# Kotlin : My app creates and saves a PDF, but i want it to open the PDF in the default viewer instead of closing

Tags: kotlin, pdf

I am trying to have my app open the PDF instead of just saving it to the downloads. I was hoping it could open it using the android default PDF viewer?

```java
private fun savePDF() {
        pdfDocument.finishPage(myPage)

        val file = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "$Number $fileName.pdf"
        )
        try {
            pdfDocument.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
            Toast.makeText(context, "PDF file generated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            previewPDF(Uri.fromFile(file))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d(tag, "Error: $e")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        pdfDocument.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**After save you pdf file, Call this below method for default pdf viewer**

```
public static void openFile(Context context,File url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    File file=url;

    Uri uri = null;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24)
    {
        uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
    }
    else
    {
        uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else {
       
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Open with"));
}
```